# React router problem fetching data when needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a tricky situation with react router 4.
Imagine I have a route

```
<Route path='/search/:term?' render={(props) => {
                return (<ProductList
                   setFlag={(flag)=>this.setState({flag})}
                   {...props}
                   />)
              }} />
```

Now you can see I am using **render** in Route which means it will **not unmount** this component at each render rather update the old instance with new props.

However, at some point inside the `ProductList` the user calls `setFlag` function which you can see updates some property in parent.

Because of this, a rerender of the parent is caused. Which also calls `componentWillReceiveProps(CWRP)` of `ProductList`.  Inside `CWRP` of `ProductList` I am always (unconditionally) fetching items with new props.

This causes my problem. **You can see that when user updated flag, there was no need to fetch data again in CWRP, because updating that flag wasn't related to my data.**

You could say that I should put some condition in CWRP that would do some check and fetch data only when it is necessary. However, I find it impossible to come up with such check. Because for example, ProductList receives a search term. I could, for example, compare a search term from the previous render to search term of new render and if they are different then to fetch data, however, that is incorrect, because even in case of same search term a fetch should be issued (maybe the data was updated on a server).

What solution do you see in such a situation? 
So that my product list doesn't fetch data everytime the flag of parent changes?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Show all classes and supporting methods needed to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Elevate your state and move your logic out of the `render` method and into a parent `container-component`, then utilize `this.setState()` to stop state updates **OR** use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to continue to allow state updates BUT stop re-renders when the `flag` hasn't been changed (either one will prevent `ProductList` from being updated):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductList from './ProductList';

export default class SearchTerms extends Component {
  state = { flag: '' };

  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => ( this.state.flag !== nextState.flag )

  handleFlag = flag => this.setState(prevState => { return this.state.flag !== flag ? { flag } : null })    

  render = () => ( <ProductList setFlag={this.handleFlag} {...this.state} {...this.props} /> )

}
```

Then the route will change to:

```
 <Route path='/search/:term?' component={SearchTerms} />
```

In addition, I'd avoid using `componentWillReceiveProps()` altogether and instead use `componentDidUpdate()`.

---

Here's an example of a parent `container-component` controlling several `component` children. The children can update the parent via a passed down parent method.

In this simple example, searchForPlayer's `onChange` and `onSubmit` updates the parent's `searchTerm` state and changes the URL query via parent's `handleSubmit` method. The URL query change triggers the parent's `componentDidUpdate` method, which then fetches new data and updates the `displayPlayerList` component.

URL before:

`/players/all`

URL after form submit:

`/players/player?number=${this.state.searchTerm}`

So if a user types out the URL to:

`/players/player?number=10`

or

`/players/fdskmsdfk?number=10`

and hits enter, it'll load a filtered list because it's only looking for a `number` query.

If they go to:

`/player/dsfdsdfdsdf`

or

`player/1223345`

or anything without a `number` query, then it'll just fetch all the players instead (**this can be handled differently, but was done for simplicity**).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xn3p3o6vq

**containers/PlayersList.js** (parent container-component)

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import qs from "qs";
import DisplayPlayerList from "../components/displayPlayerList";
import NoPlayerFound from "../components/noPlayerFound";
import SearchForPlayer from "../components/searchForPlayer";
import ServerError from "../components/serverError";
import Spinner from "../components/spinner";

export default class PlayersList extends Component {
  state = {
    err: "",
    isLoading: true,
    searchTerm: "",
    players: [],
    noplayer: "",
    number: ""
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.fetchPlayers();

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => this.props.location.search !== prevProps.location.search && this.fetchPlayers();

  fetchPlayers = () => {
    const { number } = qs.parse(this.props.location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true })

    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users${number ? `/${number}` : ""}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(players =>
        this.setState({
          err: "",
          players: !number ? [...players] : [players],
          noplayer: isEmpty(players) ? true : false,
          isLoading: false,
          number,
          searchTerm: ""
        })
      )
      .catch(err => this.setState({ err: err.toString() }));
  };

  handleChange = e => this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(`/players/player?number=${this.state.searchTerm}`);
  };

  render = () => (
    this.state.isLoading // (if isLoading is true..)
      ? <Spinner />  // (then show a spinner)
      : <div style={{ padding: 20, width: 500 }}> // (otherwise...)
          <SearchForPlayer  // (show player search form and...)
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            {...this.state}
          />
          { this.state.err // (if there's an error...)
            ? <ServerError {...this.state} /> // (show the error)
            : this.state.noplayer // (otherwise, if there's no player...)
              ? <NoPlayerFound {...this.state} /> // (show no player found)
              : <DisplayPlayerList {...this.state} /> // (otherwise, display updated list)
          }
        </div>
  );
}
```

**components/searchForPlayer.js** (child component)

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ handleChange, handleSubmit, searchTerm }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      className="uk-input"
      type="number"
      value={searchTerm}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder="Search for player by number..."
      style={{ width: 300, marginRight: 10 }}
      min={1}
    />
    <button
      disabled={!searchTerm}
      className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
      type="submit"
    >
      Search
    </button>
  </form>
);
```

**components/displayPlayerList.js** (child component)

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React from "react";

export default ({ players }) => (
  <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
    {map(players, ({ id, name, username, email }) => (
      <li style={{ margin: "10px 0" }} key={id}>
        <strong>Player # {id}</strong>
        <span> - {name}</span>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

**components/noPlayerFound.js** (child component)

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ number }) => (
  <div style={{ color: "red", padding: 20 }}>
    No player was found matching #{number}!
  </div>
);
```

**component/serverError.js** (child component)

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ err }) => (
  <div style={{ color: "red", padding: 20 }}>
    <i style={{ marginRight: 5 }} className="fas fa-exclamation-circle" /> {err}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: the flag has to live in the parent which renders ProductList (as in my example) because it pases the flag to a sibling of ProductList

Comment: my problem in simple english is basically such that Productlist should always fetch data if componentWillReceiveProps is called however except the cases when componentWillReceiveProps was called due to a update of property (a property which is not related to items of ProductList) in parents state.

Comment: The parent above passes down `flag` as `this.props.flag`. If `ProductList` needs to update the `flag`, then you use the parent's method `setFlag` as `this.props.setFlag()`. Then use componentDidUpdate to compared `this.props.flag` to `nextProps.flag`.

Comment: if I use componentDidUpdate then I need to put conditions when to update items and I can't come up with such a condition because as I said even if ProductsList was called with same search term, the ProductList should still fetch data since data could be updated in server. That is why I decieded to unconditionally fetch data in componentwillreceiveprops.

Comment: And also this doesn't seem to scale what if there are many flag like properties in parent which aren't related to data in ProductList - should I check that the re render was caused due to each of them in order to cancel the fetch?

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to change how you're fetching data. Don't do it on a state change, but on a submission.

Comment: Yeah before I had it when user clicked search button. I would fetch data and pass as props to component in Route. However the problem with this was that if user directly typed URL then the fetching part was never issued

Comment: Actually one solution is to move that flag away from parent. And update it from ProductsList using say an event emitter such that the relevant component catches it - this way the parent of ProductList doesn't get rerendered and I avoid my problem. But I thought maybe there are some other ways

Comment: In the parent's `componentDidMount`, you can check if the URL has query parameters. If not, redirect back to a landing page OR parse the queries and perform the search.

Comment: Yes but if I am doing search in componentDidMount of parent what to do when user selects new search term, in this case, the parent doesn't get rerendered -hence componentDidMount wont be called.

Comment: A single parent controls all state (including data), then passes it down to children. Then the children can update the parent's state via a passed down parent method. Basically centralize your updates to one component that updates many children instead of many individual components updating many other individual components. I'll create a sample codesandbox and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes but please make sure you first understand my situation so that you don't create sandbox in vain. When user navigates to new '/search/:term' how will you detect this in parent?

Comment: My problem is basically caused because ProductList updates a property in parent which causes ProductList to rerender. Now the update of property in parent wasn't related to data of ProductList. Hence ProductList should not fetch data. However it is tricky to detect in ProductList that the rerender was due to a property in parent which was not related to its data. What if there are many such flags? Or things that can rerender parent and which aren't related to data of ProductList? How does ProductList detect all such cases and discard fetch?

Comment: Updated answer to include codesandbox. Hopefully that'll help.